# Not able to Connect to HP ALM 12.55 using Python's Dispatch("TDApiOle80.TDConnection") Object

Tags: python

Not able to connect to HP ALM through Disppatch method .

Executing the following code:

```
import win32com.client
qc = win32com.client.Dispatch("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
```

Results in the following error on a Windows 64 bit machine with ALM version 12.55.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File"C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\sit``e-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 89, in _GetGoodDispatch IDispatch = pythoncom.connect(IDispatch) pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>File"C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\
__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)

File "C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\
dynamic.py", line 114, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName

return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
File "C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\
dynamic.py", line 91, in _GetGoodDispatch
IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you installed correct version of ALM Connectivity tool (TDConnect.exe) from `http://<youralmserver:port>/qcbin/PlugIns/TDConnectivity/TDConnect.exe`